# How can I check element have class or not in jQuery validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate

On the highlight, I try like this :

```
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
  if(element.prop("class") == "test") 
    document.getElementById('error-message-test').style.display = 'none';
}
```

There exist error :

> element.prop is not a function

How can I solve this error?

Comment: `prop` is a jQuery method. Either make sure that `element` is a jQuery object, or use `$(element).prop`.

Comment: Why this question is downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `jQuery` to wrap your element or with `hasClass` like:

`if($(element).prop("class") == "test")`

Or

`if($(element).hasClass("test"))`

Comment: Same answer has been provided by `Muhammad Yahya`, is it necessary to repeat the answer?

Comment: @Mamun, I try you first answer before edit, it works. Why you edit it?

Comment: @SuccessMan, This is another solution. OK, I will add that one too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use hasClass method of jQuery if an element has class or not.

General syntax

```
if($(element).hasClass('className'))
```

Based on your scenario

```
if($(element).hasClass('test'))
```